# Google Maps in Intellij IDEA 13.1.3

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea

I'm trying to implements a map application but I get the same error every time:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I have already imported the google_play_services_lib to my project, and I don't know more what to do

Comment: Can you post the line of code where you are getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.myapp.Map.onCreate(Map.java:25)

Comment: I have this in this part of code:public class Map extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);                                             googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(1.926, 73.400);
        Marker ciu = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("My dreamed island"));

Comment: Is googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); the line giving you the exception?  You should edit your question and post the exact line giving you the error and also your main.xml layout file and maybe even the manifest file with your map API key removed.

Comment: I have a simple Android app that uses Google Maps API v2 on GitHub if you want to compare your code to it: https://github.com/welctb01/GolfBuddy